# How do acquire a xml string for a child using msxml4?

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

Using MSXML4, I am creating and saving an xml file:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr m_pXmlDoc;
//add some elements with data
SaveToDisk(static_cast<std::string>(m_pXmlDoc->xml));
```

I now need to acquire a substring from `m_pXmlDoc->xml` and save it.  For example, if the full xml is:

```
<data>
    <child1>
        <A>data</A>
            <One>data</One>
        <B>data</B>
    </child1>
</data>
```

I want to store this substring instead:

```
<A>data</A>
    <One>data</One>
<B>data</B>
```

How do I get this substring using MXML4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath queries. See the MSDN [documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764716%28VS.85%29.aspx) for querying nodes. Basically you need to call the `selectNodes` API with the appropriate XPath expression that matches the part of the DOM you are interested in.

```
// Query a node-set.
MSXML4::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr pnl = pXMLDom->selectNodes(L"//child/*");
```